# How to retrieve data from mysql php when click on spinner item android?.... it shows " app unfortunately has stopped"

Tags: php, android, eclipse

I want to retrieve data from mysql database using webserver php when user click on item in spinner in android app .... but it shows that app has unfortunately stopped.... and don't know what is the error....
**JSONparser class**

```
    public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {

        if (method == "POST") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf- 8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}


 }
```

**plantgrow class**

```
    public class Plantgrow extends Activity {
Spinner plantts;
Intent grow;
Button groow;
TextView info;
String data,select;
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

private static String url_imp_info = "http://10.0.2.2:850/planting/plantinfo.php";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_INFOS = "infos";
private static final String TAG_PINFO= "pinfo";


JSONArray infos = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_plantgrow);
    plantts=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    info=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_plantinfo);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>   adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.plants,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    plantts.setAdapter(adapter);
    groow=(Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_grow);


    plantts.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Object item=arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
    select=item.toString();


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });

    groow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            grow=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Planting.class);
            startActivity(grow);
        }
    });
    new GetInfo().execute();

}
class GetInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("select", select));

    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_imp_info, "GET",
            params);

    Log.d("All names: ", json.toString());

    try {

        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success == 1) {
            infos = json.getJSONArray(TAG_INFOS);
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = infos.getJSONObject(i);
             data = c.getString(TAG_PINFO);

            }
        } 
        else {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2.class);

            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
    super.onPostExecute(file_url);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            info.setText(data);

        }
    });
}   

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_plantgrow, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**php code**

```
<?php



$response = array();

require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

 $db = new DB_CONNECT();

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");

    if (isset($_GET["select"])) {

$select = $_GET['select'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT importantInfo FROM plantinfo WHERE plantName=$select") or     die(mysql_error());



if (!empty($result)) {


if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{

    $response["infos"] = array();


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


    $info = array();


$info["pinfo"] = $row["importantInfo"];

    array_push($response["infos"], $info);

}

    $response["success"] = 1;



echo json_encode($response);
} else {


$response["success"] = 0;

$response["message"] = "No info found";


echo json_encode($response);
}

    } else 
{           $response["success"] = 0;

        $response["message"] = "No info found";



    echo json_encode($response);

}



} else {


$response["success"] = 0;

$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";



echo json_encode($response);

}

?>
```

**logCat**

```
03-25 19:48:58.737: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:58.747: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:58.957: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:58.987: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.486: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 86K, 8% free 2526K/2728K, paused  28ms, total 30ms
03-25 19:48:59.506: I/dalvikvm-heap(770): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.578MB for 3145744-  byte allocation
03-25 19:48:59.546: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 5596K/5804K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
03-25 19:48:59.596: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5596K/5804K,  paused 4ms+14ms, total 52ms
03-25 19:48:59.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.787: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.827: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.837: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.887: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.917: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.927: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.927: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.927: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.927: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.927: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:48:59.947: D/gralloc_goldfish(770): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-25 19:49:00.187: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.237: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0  
03-25 19:49:00.297: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.297: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.507: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0 
03-25 19:49:00.507: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.507: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.556: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.736: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.736: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.766: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.766: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.826: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:00.826: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.371: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.371: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.417: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.430: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.933: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:01.936: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.036: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.036: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.326: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.366: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.377: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.377: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.457: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.457: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.527: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.537: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.727: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be    doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:02.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.747: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.857: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.887: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:02.887: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:03.257: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:03.257: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:04.427: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 3% free 5723K/5896K, paused 266ms, total 297ms
03-25 19:49:04.587: I/dalvikvm-heap(770): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.701MB for 3145744-byte allocation
03-25 19:49:04.927: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 3% free 8790K/8972K, paused  12ms+39ms, total 332ms
03-25 19:49:05.977: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.007: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.277: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.456: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.516: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.546: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.576: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.576: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.576: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.666: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.666: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.706: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:06.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.807: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.807: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.827: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:06.848: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.027: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.077: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.097: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.127: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.217: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.217: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.727: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:07.736: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.117: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.417: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.467: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:08.477: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.517: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.517: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.517: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.738: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.738: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.897: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:08.897: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:08.907: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.037: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.037: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.366: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.366: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.406: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.406: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
 03-25 19:49:09.497: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.497: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.537: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.590: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.697: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.877: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.887: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:09.897: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:09.907: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:10.150: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:10.150: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:10.210: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:11.517: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 66K, 3% free 8899K/9084K, paused     277ms, total 315ms
03-25 19:49:11.727: I/dalvikvm-heap(770): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.801MB for 3145744-byte allocation
03-25 19:49:12.126: D/dalvikvm(770): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 2% free 11965K/12160K, paused 44ms+44ms, total 399ms
03-25 19:49:12.917: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:12.957: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.047: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.217: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.298: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.316: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.337: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.337: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.356: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.476: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.476: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.526: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 59 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:13.546: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.546: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.586: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.586: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.596: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.606: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.807: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.847: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.877: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:13.908: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:14.481: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:14.517: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:14.548: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:14.548: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.426: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.487: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.487: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.506: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.637: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.637: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.707: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.777: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:16.897: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.077: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.087: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:17.097: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.117: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.599: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.599: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:17.637: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.354: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.404: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.514: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.845: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.904: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.914: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.924: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.934: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:18.934: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.023: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.023: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.033: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 138 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:19.033: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.054: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.284: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.355: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.405: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.434: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.534: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.534: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.614: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.614: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.964: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.964: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:19.964: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.014: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.034: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.034: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.084: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.084: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.084: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.084: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.094: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.094: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.104: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.114: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.134: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.144: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.144: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.144: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.174: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.174: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.174: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.174: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.204: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.204: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.204: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:20.204: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:21.736: E/JSON Parser(770): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value Unknown of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
03-25 19:49:21.745: W/dalvikvm(770): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at     java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.example.agricultureguide.Plantgrow$GetInfo.doInBackground(Plantgrow.java:102)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.example.agricultureguide.Plantgrow$GetInfo.doInBackground(Plantgrow.java:1)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-25 19:49:21.814: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  ... 4 more
03-25 19:49:21.954: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:22.114: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:22.124: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:23.704: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:23.704: I/Choreographer(770): Skipped 413 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-25 19:49:23.714: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:23.914: W/Trace(770): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0

03-25 19:49:28.765: I/Process(770): Sending signal. PID: 770 SIG: 9
03-25 19:49:31.345: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:32.144: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:32.176: W/Trace(795): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-25 19:49:33.025: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 52K, 7% free 2526K/2696K, paused 60ms, total 66ms
03-25 19:49:33.084: I/dalvikvm-heap(795): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.578MB for 3145744-byte allocation
03-25 19:49:33.214: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 4% free 5596K/5772K, paused 58ms, total 58ms
03-25 19:49:33.334: D/dalvikvm(795): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 5596K/5772K, paused 17ms+6ms, total 120ms
```

**stacktrace console**

```
 [2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] ------------------------------
 [2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] Android Launch!
 [2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] adb is running normally.
[2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] Performing     com.example.agricultureguide.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator  'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'agriculture'
[2014-03-27 22:16:16 - AgricultureGuide] Uploading AgricultureGuide.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-03-27 22:16:30 - AgricultureGuide] Installing AgricultureGuide.apk...
[2014-03-27 22:16:36 - AgricultureGuide] Success!
[2014-03-27 22:16:36 - AgricultureGuide] Starting activity com.example.agricultureguide.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-03-27 22:16:38 - AgricultureGuide] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent {   act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]   cmp=com.example.agricultureguide/.MainActivity }
```

Comment: that is not complete..when you run your program you will receive an exception.Also post it too.

Comment: i don't know .... i just copy the content of logCat.... you mean that i didn't copy all of it???? what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Check the success condition in onPostExecute()

```
  if(success==1)
    {    info.setText(data);
    }
   else
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main2.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

onPostExecute() runs in UI thread only so you can avoid runOnUiThread there

Comment: i tried it ... but it shows also that the app has stopped

Comment: i post it now          ,,,,

Answer (score -1):

it worked with me when I add tag for items into spinner using `StringWithTag` class